# Error after splash screen in visual studio 2010 - Windows Phone

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have finally finished creating an app in Microsoft Visual Studio. And decided to change the name of the project folder, thinking this would rename the application when I publish it (I though this very stupidly).

I tried to debug the app to see if it changed the name, but it just threw up a bunch of errors (of course).

So I changed the name of the project folder back to it's original name.

However this is my real problem: That now I have tried debugging the app (after changing back the project folder name) I get past the loading splash screen to find just a black screen with no functionality! What on earth have I done?! And does anyone have any ideas to help?

Additional info: There are no errors/warnings. It is a panorama app.

Comment: Make a copy of the project - then, in the project folder, delete the BIN and OBJ folder, now in VS 2012, rebuild and see if anything changes?

Comment: After doing what @NeilTurner suggested, place breakpoints in `App.xaml.cs` and walk through the execution until you find the point where the app no longer behaves as expected.